# Consider stopping times $S$ and $T$ for a filtration $(\mathcal{F}_n)$. Show that $\mathcal{F}_{\min(S,T)} = \mathcal{F}_{S}\cap \mathcal{F}_{T}$.

Tags: measure-theory, stopping-times

I'm trying to solve this question but my argument works for $\mathcal{F}_{\max(S,T)} = \mathcal{F}_{S}\cap \mathcal{F}_{T}$. I'm wondering if anyone can confirm if this question is a typo and should be asking for $\max(S,T)$ instead of $\min(S,T)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It holds that

$$\mathcal{F}_{\max\{S,T\}} = \sigma(\mathcal{F}_S,\mathcal{F}_T),$$

see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/745249/36150) for a proof, and

$$\mathcal{F}_{\min\{S,T\}} = \mathcal{F}_S \cap \mathcal{F}_T$$

as is shown e.g. in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/439914/36150).

SO: No, there is no typo in the question. Note that, in general,

$$\mathcal{F}_{S} \cap \mathcal{F}_T \subsetneq \sigma(\mathcal{F}_S,\mathcal{F}_T).$$

Comment: Thanks for answering. If we're considering stopping times $S$ and $T$ where $S \leq T$ and we're considering $\left\{min(S,T) \leq n \right\}$ is it possible for $T > n$?

Comment: @BobCobb Yeah, sure... just take constant stopping times, e.g. $S:= n$ and $T:=n+1$ (for some fixed $n$), then $\Omega = \{\min(S,T)\leq n\}$, but $T(\omega)>n$ for all $\omega$.

Comment: Ok, so do we need to examine a case where $S \leq T$ and $T > n$ to complete the proof when we assume $F \in \mathcal{F}_{min(S,T)}$?

Comment: @BobCobb I don't know which proof you are actually talking about. If you refer to one of the proofs I linked in my answer, then please ask your question there.

Comment: I'm not able to comment there because I don't have a reputation of at least 50. I am referring to this answer http://math.stackexchange.com/a/439914/73120

Comment: @BobCobb I see, but unfortunately I still don't understand your question. For $F \in \mathcal{F}_{\min(S,T)}$ we want to show that $F \in \mathcal{F}_S$ and $F \in \mathcal{F}_T$. In the linked proof I just used the identities $$\{T \leq n\} = \{T \leq n\} \cap \{\min(S,T) \leq n\}$$ and $$\{S \leq n\} = \{S \leq n\} \cap \{\min(S,T) \leq n\}$$ to prove this.